# How to search for latest file in folder and if not found then open dialog box with restrictions?

Tags: excel, vba

The goal is to combine two functions or make them compatible with each other. There is errors when it comes to the part when the path of the chosen file is not refer to in the same manner as the path of the found file within the loop if available in the folder.

I get an error. See "HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR" at

`Dim closedBook As Workbook: Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)`

```vb
'main code that run is doing something like search for file within folder,
'loop and get the latest file and generates a path and name for next
'function which is to copy a sheet from the found file over to the main
'workbook and so.

'What I'm trying to to is to build a failsafe, lets say file is not pushed
'or placed whin this predestinated folder, then instead of doing nothing,
'dialog box opens up and files gets chosen instead.


Option Explicit

Sub ImportAndFormatData()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Const sFolderPath As String = "C:\Temp\"
    
    'Search for newest file
    
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "_pr11*.xlsx")
    If Len(sFileName) = 0 Then Call OpenDialogBox
    
    Dim cuDate As Date, sFileDate As Date, cuPath As String, sFilePath As String
    
    Do Until Len(sFileName) = 0
        cuPath = sFolderPath & sFileName
        cuDate = FileDateTime(cuPath)
        'Debug.Print "Current:  " & cuDate & "  " & cuPath ' print current
        If cuDate > sFileDate Then
            sFileDate = cuDate
            sFilePath = cuPath
        End If
        sFileName = Dir
    Loop
    'Debug.Print "Result:   " & sFileDate & "  " & sFilePath ' print result
    

    'Open newest file - HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
    Dim closedBook As Workbook: Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
    closedBook.Sheets("Analyse").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PR11_P3")
    closedBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

'code dose not end here but that part don't need to be included here since
'its just formatting

End Sub
```

In `OpenDialogBox`, I'm tying to enforce a specific title (only this file/report is correct source for the entire code or rather rest of the code).

See "GIVES ERROR DOSENT WORK" at

`.Filters.Add "Excel filer", "_pr11*.xlsx?", 1`

```vb
Sub OpenDialogBox()

    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    With fd
        .Filters.Clear
        .Title = "Välj valfri PR11"
        .Filters.Add "Excel filer", "_pr11*.xlsx?", 1 'GIVES ERROR DOSENT WORK
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
    
        If .Show = True Then
            Debug.Print .SelectedItems(1)
            Debug.Print Dir(.SelectedItems(1))
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: "error" is not a very useful description of what happens when you run your code.  What is the specific error message/messages you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This combines both the `Dir()` and `FileDialog` approaches:

```vb
Sub ImportAndFormatData()
    Dim fSelected As String, wb As Workbook

    fSelected = InputFile()
    If Len(fSelected) > 0 Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fSelected)
        wb.Sheets("Analyse").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PR11_P3")
        wb.Close False
    End If
End Sub

Function InputFile() As String
    Const SRC_FOLDER As String = "C:\Temp\"
    Dim f, fSelected As String, latestDate As Date, fdt
    
    f = Dir(SRC_FOLDER & "*_pr11*.xlsx") 'first check the configured folder for a match
    If Len(f) > 0 Then
        'found matching file at specified path: loop for the newest file
        Do While Len(f) > 0
            fdt = FileDateTime(SRC_FOLDER & f)
            If fdt > latestDate Then
                fSelected = SRC_FOLDER & f
                latestDate = fdt
            End If
            f = Dir()
        Loop
        InputFile = fSelected
    Else
        'no match at specified path - allow user selection
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
            .Filters.Clear
            .Title = "Välj valfri PR11"
            .Filters.Add "Excel filer", "*.xlsx" 'filter only allows extension: no filename wildcards...
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show Then InputFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I'm getting undefine variable error

Comment: On which line ?  There are no undeclared variables in the posted code...

Comment: Dim closedBook As Workbook: Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open(fSelected)

The path of the found or chosen file is not working, In my original code the path was set to sFilePath but only when the search function and the loop did the jobb, the dialog box did not do this (well it did but I couldn't combine the two propeller) and so I ended up asking for a way to combine the two code

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: If file is found then it works, if file is chosen the action of moving the specified sheet don't work, and there is no error message so I don't know how to explain this

Comment: I guess the else function needs to grab file name and path and that needs to be converted to a string (I'm just guessing here) and then there has to be yet another if function for the wb.sheets copy section?

Comment: Put a break on `If Len(fSelected) > 0 Then` and run the code - what is in `fSelected` after manually selecting the input file?

Comment: Done.

The file with the path that was chosen, then wb Nothing Woorkbook

Comment: The code above works fine for me.  I don't know why it wouldn't work in your environment.

Comment: So I restarted, grabbed a new workbook, added this and ran it, work fine, startet copy over my used moduls, exported my work in progress modules  and the discarded my original file, restarted again, started up my file my workbook and used the modules and functions using my textboxes bound to each module and subs and so on, everything runs smoothly so really I cant say what or why, nevertheless though, THANK you!

Comment: OK - good to hear you got it working.

Comment: I do have another question, when dialog box is open if I chose to not chose a file then it gives a error, can I put the last Else into its on IF and then write a else do nothing function/end sub?

Comment: On which line is the error, and what's the error message?  Always helps here to be specific.

Comment: Oh well I sorted it out so nvm :)

Thanks again!

Comment: Tim if I may ask, how can I ignore getting error msg if no file is selected when dialog box pops up (say user choose to cancel the operation) atm, this action results in error and I would like to ignore this error (so user doesn't have to jump into vba code) I have tried to rewrite if then then else do nothing but I cant implant my logic in a correct manner. Would appreciate you time guidens on this if possible.

Comment: If the user is asked to select a file and cancels the dialog then `fSelected` will be an empty string and the following `If Len(fSelected)>0` test will catch that and there will be no error.  At least that's what happens for me when testing.  If you're seeing an error it would be helpful to describe exactly what error that is, and on which line of code it occurs.

Comment: Well here is the thing, and its hard to explain, in where en sub accurse in your code/answer, there my formatting begins (then end sub, so just after end it I start with rest of my code, almost entirely formatting of the sheet) since the function is, look in folder, get latest or if there is no file then chose with a dialog box. So when there is no file in folder and then the user presses cancel on prompt of choosing a file manually my formatting code stats to run and this is where the error i accruing which I need to handel somehow.

Comment: Since I want to keep this simple, lets say this is the only thing my code dose after the end if and before the ens sub, Sheets("Analyse").Select
        Columns("AC:AE").Delete
        Columns("O:Q").Delete
        Columns("I:M").Delete
        Columns("E:G").Delete
        Columns("A:B").Delete
Range("A1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("PR11_P3").Select
        Range("A10").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Analyse").Delete
End sub

Comment: I understand that it doesn't really matter what the rest of the code is or doing, since its trying to operate on something that is not there. So I guess best thing would be to output a msgbox that would tell the user to either chose a file or exit excel. I'm trying to minimize, actually eliminate all and any pop up boxen where the user has to take a stand and adress the error in any code.

Comment: Anything which needs to happen only if there's a file to work with goes inside the `If Len(fSelected) > 0 Then` block.